# Why do I get an scientific notation where it is not necessary?

Tags: pandas

In my dataframe which lists wars, duration of war and death toll, I replaced symbols like "+" and "," to get just a number, represented as a string. Then I transormed it in a numeric. This is the function:

```
def death_range(df):
    df["death_range"] = df["death_range"].str.replace(",","")
    
    df["death_base"] = df["death_range"].str.split("–").str[0]
    df["death_max"] = df["death_range"].str.split("–").str[-1]
    
    df["death_base"] = df["death_base"].str.replace("+"," ")
    df["death_base"] = df["death_base"].str.replace(r"\D","", regex=True)
    
    df["death_max"] = df["death_max"].str.replace("+"," ")
    df["death_max"] = df["death_max"].str.replace(r"\D","", regex=True)
    
    df["death_base"] = pd.to_numeric(df["death_base"], errors='coerce')
    df["death_max"] = pd.to_numeric(df["death_max"], errors='coerce')
    
    return df
```

When doing:

```
df_cp['death_max'].max()
```

To see what was the most deadliest war in history, I get this number:

```
1700000040000000.0
```

I did the following to see which war it was:

```
max_death_war = df_cp[df_cp['death_max']== 1700000040000000.0]
```

I get:

```
World War I | 17000000-40000000 | 1914–1918 | Allied Powers vs. Central Powers  | Worldwide | World War I   | 1.700000e+15  | 1.700000e+15  | 1914  | 1918
```

These numbers looks correct: 17000000-40000000. I don't understand why the above function turns them into: 1.700000e+15 (1700000040000000.0)

**Can you explain this behavior? What did I do wrong in my function?**

Comment: "e" stands for `10**`, not Euler's number. See Wikipedia: [Scientific notation § E notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation)

Comment: The dash you're trying to split on is an en-dash (Unicode U+2013), but the one in the `death_range` field is a hyphen (Unicode U+2D), so it doesn't actually split. If you have some rows with an en-dash and some with a hyphen, you can split on a regex, `r"-|\u2013""`.

Comment: I should mention, I noticed it because the dash in the string `"–"` looked a *tiny bit* too wide, but I can also notice it by copying the function into VSCode, where I have the setting `editor.unicodeHighlight.nonBasicASCII` turned on, so the en-dash gets highlighted.